# Signed kernel modules - "not signed with trusted key"

Tags: kernel-modules

**Issue:**

I'm trying to use signed kernel modules, but getting a failure for the `insmod` command:

`PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`

There is a potentially related error message during Linux boot:

```
[    3.342888] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    3.391774] Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate (-129)
```

The command `cat /proc/keys` shows `.builtin_trusted_keys: empty`

**Setup:**

The 4.9.x kernel was compiled with the following defconfig options:

```
...
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA256=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH="sha256"
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING=y
CONFIG_KEYS_DEBUG_PROC_KEYS=y
CONFIG_PERSISTENT_KEYRINGS=y
CONFIG_ENCRYPTED_KEYS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT=y
CONFIG_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_SECURITYFS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_PATH=y
CONFIG_HARDENED_USERCOPY=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SMACK=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SMACK_BRINGUP=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_DAC=y
...
```

Modules were signed with a command:
`sign-file sha256 certs/signing_key.pem certs/signing_key.x509 <.ko>`

**Comments:**

I assume I need to fix the in-kernel X.509 certificate loading error, but I haven't come across how to do that.  I thought the file `certs/signing_key.pem` generated during kernel compilation would be wrapped into the kernel but it appears not based on `/proc/keys`.  I don't want to disable signing or allow unsigned modules, I just want to sign them properly with a trusted key.  If anyone has advice, that would be much appreciated.

The posts I've found regarding nvidia drivers and Ubuntu/Fedora haven't yielded any progress yet. Example:
[PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455189/pkcs7-signature-not-signed-with-a-trusted-key)

Answer (score 1):

I think the kernel compilation expects the signing_key.* files in the base directory of the kernel source tree and not under a ”certs” subdirectory. The compilation process should automatically sign the standard modules for you; only third-party modules should need manual signing.

Also, my old script for compiling a 4.9.* kernel with signed modules had the certificate file in DER format. Perhaps it was necessary?

In the 4.14 and newer kernels, the procedure is a bit different: there is a kernel configuration option for specifying the pathname of the certificate file.

Comment: I tried specifying `SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=certs/signing_key.pem`, but the result was the same.  I think you are on to something regarding paths though.

Comment: Another data point: I did not create the files `certs/signing_key.*`.  They were created during the kernel build process at that location.  That's why I'm a bit confused why the kernel isn't pulling the key in by default.

Answer (score 0):

@bjornruffians
You can create your own x509.genekey file and copy it in source of kernel i.e. in certs/ folder before compilation. 
**Warning:** do not copy your custom/manual generated signing_key.pem or any other file except x509.genekey in cert folder because kernel will auto generate signing_key.x509 and signing_key.pem file with respect to your x509.genekey file.